# How to Find SSRS report version in report server

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Could anyone tell me that how to find out the version of report in report server,
Whether it is ssrs 2012 or ssrs 2008 r2.

Thanks.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630446%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: thanks for your reply. I need version of particular deployed report in report .

Comment: I need version of particular deployed report in report server. Could any one let me know how to find.

Answer (score 1):

Download the report and open the .rdl file with a notepad or XML editor, the second row should be something like this:

```
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
```

You can find some info related the reportdefinition

Hope this helps you